# HP Envy x360 TouchScreen not working

Tags: hp, touchscreen

I have tried a couple of things I found all over, but none have worked. Here is some information about the laptop.

product: HP ENVY x360 Convertible 15m-bq0xx
       product: 8311
          product: AMD FX-9800P RADEON R7, 12 COMPUTE CORES 4C+8G

I'm running 17.10 and so far the touchsceen is the only thing not working.

xinput

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ xwayland-pointer:13                       id=6    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ xwayland-relative-pointer:13              id=7    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ xwayland-keyboard:13                      id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

This is what I get running xinput, the odd thing is there use to be xwayland-touch:13 with an id of 9 but it is now gone. Rather than mess it up more I thought I would ask for help.

Answer (score 0):

It may not be completely compatible with your laptop (I am using the 15m-bq100 Ryzen 5 model), but try [this patch/hack](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=198715#c14), or an acpi override further down. I have the patch on a 4.16.6 kernel, and it does work, but to a point. It is still being developed, so be a bit patient.

Additional Info:

Based on testing with the patch, the edges do not always register, which forces me to readjust drawing programs like Krita and Inkscape and I have had it stop responding after 3-5 hours of use, which is mitigated by disabling/reenabling i2c_hid. I have had limited luck with the ACPI override, where it fails to grab i2c-ELAN0732:00 at boot.

Comment: Hi tdis! It would be great if you could add more specific information to your answer, like what the limits are to the functionality of the patch you suggested.